# Solr document Submission

Tags: solr

I am new in the solr technology.Can you please tell me how a document can submit to solr using user interface.Is it necessary to create xml of the document first?I expect a simplest way of document indexing..

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

The default Solr RequestHandler (from 4.0) supports four formats: `XML`, `JSON`, `CSV` and `javabin`. There's a page under the Admin interface to submit documents to the index (select the core and `Documents`).

There are [examples of each of the formats](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers) available in the Solr reference guide. If you're using a client library, the library will usually handle this for you anyways, and use an appropriate format depending on which language it's written in and what built-in libraries are available.

The simplest format for manually adding documents is probably JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Doc 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Doc 2"
  }
]
```

You can also use the [DataImportHandler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) to import data locally at the server, such as from an SQL-database. In that case you don't submit the actual rows to the server, but you tell the handler to fetch the rows and create documents for you.